# Protect the execution of my php script called from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to protect ajaxRequest.open php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897680/how-to-protect-ajaxrequest-open-php-script)

im making a ajax call from jquery to a php script located in my own server like: `$.ajax({ url: 'ajax.php', ....`

Its any way to protect the execution of this file directly? I mean, some IF statement that only let the code begin if the file ajax.php is called from *lets say* an jquery script writen in origin.html and NOT if the file is called directly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
 // code that has to be executed in response to ajax req.
}
```

ref: [AJAX only access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393904/ajax-only-access/1393923#1393923)

Comment: This can be easily faked so relying on this way is not 100% secure.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the page only receives passed variables using `$_POST['']` RATHER THAN `$_GET[''] / $_REQUEST['']` variables, can act as a first line of defence.

This is because a POST is harder to fake and variables cannot be passed directly in the code through the URL like `http://website.com?variable=hacked`

Answer (score 1):

If you want 100% certainty then you have to make some kind of authentication for that. One option could be to store a random key in a database from the page with the ajax script on it. Then pass that key to the ajax.php file. In the ajax file you check if the key is in the database. If so run the script, delete the key. If it's now in the database it's not a valid request.